# SharedPreferences in a method

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I want to edit my sharedpreferences in a method and save a value. If I do so, it says:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference
```

I have an other activity where it worked (but the code was in the oncreate method).  Here, the code doesn't seem to work.
Here is my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

SharedPreferences myPrefs;

//some irrelevant code here and there

public void login(View view){
//some more irrelevant code
bt_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String theusername = String.valueOf(username.getText());
                String thepass = String.valueOf(pass.getText());
                if (theusername.equals("schueler") && thepass.equals("123456")) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("LehrerPref", false);
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login erfolgreich! :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login fehlgeschlagen :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                if (theusername.equals("lehrer") && thepass.equals("14869")) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("LehrerPref", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login erfolgreich! :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login fehlgeschlagen :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
}

}
```

The parts within the if statements are the ones throwing the errors.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: you never initalize `myPrefs`

Comment: how do I initiate it?

Comment: in onCreate: `myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important things in programming is writing clear code. Don't duplicate code.

Here is sample solution:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt_SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String theusername = String.valueOf(username.getText());
            String thepass = String.valueOf(pass.getText());
            if (theusername.equals("schueler") && thepass.equals("123456")) {
                setLehrerPref(false);
                startFrontPage();
            } else if (theusername.equals("lehrer") && thepass.equals("14869")) {
                setLehrerPref(true);
                startFrontPage();
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login fehlgeschlagen :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setLehrerPref(boolean b){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("LehrerPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("LehrerPref", b);
    editor.apply();
}

private void startFrontPage(){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login erfolgreich! :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Frontpage.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :-)